# Design for ribbon-based applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

How do you structure your project for ribbon based projects, when using WPF?
I use Microsoft's Ribbon control and I wonder if I should have a single 
view for the main app, but two separate view models one for the ribbon
and another for the window part below the ribbon.

Comment: Is your window part, the same functionality as your ribbon?

Comment: Nope, the window is on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a very subjective question... I'm actually surprised that it hasn't been closed yet (we have many keen question closers on this site). The answer to your question of course depends on what the application does, its size, the developer's style and preference of programming, etc.

I personally just prefer to hardcode the controls into my `Ribbon` rather than generating them from a view model and templates. It *does* make the code page large, but I'd rather have that then be confused as to what goes where and when.

I generally prefer to simply have one property of type `BassViewModel` in my `MainViewModel` class and that is data bound to a `ContentControl` in 'the window part below the Ribbon as you call it. Then I just set this property to the relevant view model dependant upon the users' view selection in the `Ribbon`.

Comment: Reading your comment again I think I like what you said: "It does make the code page large, but I'd rather have that then be confused as to what goes where and when.".